# Running fine in online compliers but is not running in terminal. PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

```
if flag == True:

    print("congatulations you have guessed number correctly in",7-guesses,"Guesses")

    #if flag is false print sorry

    else:    #error line

        print("Sorry!! you failed to guess number correctly in 7 Guesses")

    #open report.txt in appending mode and write user name and guesses taken

    with open("report.txt", "a") as myfile:

        myfile.write(user_name+"\t"+str(7-guesses)+"\n")
```

When i run this on online compilers, it works fine. But when i run this code in terminal, is says

```
"File "Hw6.py", line 59
    else:
       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: ``if flag is True``

Answer (score 0):

Your else is not indented properly try

```
if flag == True:

    print("congatulations you have guessed number correctly in",7-guesses,"Guesses")

    #if flag is false print sorry

else:  
    print("Sorry!! you failed to guess number correctly in 7 Guesses")

        #open report.txt in appending mode and write user name and guesses taken

    with open("report.txt", "a") as myfile:

        myfile.write(user_name+"\t"+str(7-guesses)+"\n")
```